# Uploadify IO Error - related to Apache user?

Tags: php, jquery, apache, uploadify

I am recently using Uploadify and have deployed it to 3 different servers: Windows, LAMP with CGI PHP and LAMP with PHP running as module. I developed the code in the Windows server and when I deployed it to my Linux CGI PHP, the Uploadify works perfectly.

However, when I deployed it in the Linux PHP module, I got IO Error in my Uploadify. The interesting thing is I also have other simple upload code using PHP and it works perfectly in this Linux PHP Module server.

Anyone here has the same experience? Is it related to the fact that the user who runs Apache server is apache while the owner of the directory where the files are uploaded to is different user. I had chmod 777 this directory but still it doesn't work.

Any helps would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Anything in the php and apache error logs?

Comment: Needs a more detailed error description. Where exactly are you getting a message and from whom?

Comment: Uploadify uses Flash. If I remember correctly, the IO Error comes from problems with the input to and output from Flash.

Comment: @marc-b: No PHP and Apache error log

Comment: @pekka: This IO Error comes from Uploadify, I think it is Flash application embedded to HTML

Comment: @z0q: I even tried to post through a simple HTML form to uploadify/uploadify.php (the PHP handler of Uploadify) and it works. It can upload file, so I think it is not a common permission problem.

Comment: Yes, I know. But Uploadify does not directly call `uploadify.php`. Instead it posts the data to Flash and Flash posts it to the PHP file. That's why I think there must be a problem with Flash.

Comment: What error message are you getting exactly? What does it look like?

Comment: @Michael Pater: a friend suggested that it may be related to the server that using SSL/ HTTPS without proper certificate. Now I am waiting for my client's feedback after I requested him to disable HTTPS.

Comment: @Pekka: no error in log or browser, only IO Error message displayed below Uploadify progress bar

Comment: If it works in other servers, try to verify the server configuration where if fails. For example, max_post_size directive.

Comment: If it works in other servers, try to verify the server configuration where it fails. For example, max_post_size directive. But, really I had the same problem and I couldn't fix it. Finally y changed uplodify and now I use this: http://valums.com/ajax-upload/ good luck.

Comment: @Carlos: thanks. It doesn't use Flash, so I will give it a try. Hopefully it is more realiable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just got a confirmation from the client, when he moved the site to non HTTPS, all uploads work properly. So the reason caused this problem is using uploadify on HTTPS site without proper certificate. The thing is the Flash component of uploadify just simply give an IO Error as opposed to clear and detailed error message.

Actually got an idea about possibility of HTTPS causing error from a Wordpress forum discussing AJAX uploader using Flash.

Thanks to all comments, I believe many possible causes as suggested in the comments, and this HTTPS is just one of them.

Answer (score 0):

check the php.ini settings for the values of these variables:

```
max_execution_time
max_post_size
uploaded_file_max_size
post_max_size
file_uploads
```

Also, these entries in the .htaccess helped me previously:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Content-Type "^multipart/form-data;" "MODSEC_NOPOSTBUFFERING=Do not buffer file uploads"
```

and/or

(security risk!)

```
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
```

If you haven't already, add this to the 'onError' callback function (function(a,b,c,d)):

```
alert("Error: "+d.type+"      Info: "+d.info");
```

Comment: Thanks, I have done all of these before submitting the question here. The correct answer is the one I posted below (got it from my client but would like to share it as I don't see it anywhere in the Internet).

I believe your suggested steps above is also useful to solve similar problems